# Passing information to forms from databases in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In order to populate a form with information from a database, I do something like this:

```
@if($parameter_passed_in_the_controller)
<input type="text" value=@($parameter_passed_in_the_controller)></input>
@else
<input type="text" value=""></input>
@endif
```

While this works I wonder if there is other way to do in a less archaic way, or if this is actually the correct way to do this.

Comment: I think its all about preferences :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is

```
@if($parameter_passed_in_the_controller)
<input type="text" value={{ $parameter_passed_in_the_controller }}></input>
@else
<input type="text" value=""></input>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value given to the input is big then this is the correct way.

But if you are passing a variable or request, then you can use another way like this --

```
<input type="text" value={{ $parameter_passed_in_the_controller ? 'echo if it is true' : 'echo if it is false' }}></input>
```

`?` ends the if statement and `:` used for else

Answer (score 1):

If you have some sort of CRUD going on, or in any case when you are fetching a model from database, you can use "form model binding".

A short tutorial [here](https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-23/laravel-5-application-form-model-binding-laravelcollective-forms-html-library-bootstrap-framework/).

As explained in the tutorial you use the laravelcollective library and then create the form in such way

```
{!! Form::model($yourModel, ['action' => 'YourController@yourMethod']) !!}

    //here you can create fields like so
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('field_name', 'Field label') !!}
      {!! Form::text('field_name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What i like about this method is that it is also taking care of filling the form with "old" values in case of validation failure and such.